# ERROR: integer out of range In postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Below is my table schema (I am using PostgreSQL 9.6.1)

```
  my_table
  ------------
  table_id SERIAL PRIMRY KEY,
  A1 INTEGER,
  A2 INTEGER,
  A3 INTEGER,
  A4 INTEGER,
  A5 INTEGER,
  A6 INTEGER,
  A7 INTEGER,
  A8 INTEGER,
  A9 INTEGER,
  A10 INTEGER,
  A11 INTEGER,
  A12 INTEGER,
  A13 INTEGER,
  A14 INTEGER,
  A15 INTEGER,
  A16 DOUBLE PRECISION,
  A17 DOUBLE PRECISION
```

and i am trying to run below query in order to create a new table.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_2 AS
  SELECT
    B1                                              AS C1                           
    B3                                              AS C2,
    B5                                              AS C3,
    B7                                              AS C4 ,
    B9                                              AS C5,
    B11                                             AS C6 ,
    B1 / CAST( NULLIF(B3, 0) AS FLOAT)              AS C7,
    B1 / CAST( NULLIF(B5, 0) AS FLOAT)         AS C8,
    B1 / CAST( NULLIF(B7, 0) AS FLOAT)        AS C9,
    B1 / CAST( NULLIF(B9, 0) AS FLOAT)     AS C10,
    B1 / CAST( NULLIF(B11, 0) AS FLOAT)     AS C11,
    B3 / CAST( NULLIF(B5, 0) AS FLOAT)      AS C12,
    B5 / CAST( NULLIF(B7, 0 )* NULLIF(B9,0) AS FLOAT)  AS C13,

    B2                                    AS C14 ,
    B4                                  AS C15,
    B6                                    AS C16,
    B8                                  AS C17,
    B10                                AS C18,
    B12                                AS C19,
    B2 / CAST(NULLIF(B4, 0) AS FLOAT)  AS C20,
    B2 / CAST(NULLIF(B6, 0) AS FLOAT)  AS C21,
    B2 / CAST(NULLIF(B8, 0) AS FLOAT)  AS C22,
    B2 / CAST(NULLIF(B10, 0) AS FLOAT) AS C23,
    B2 / CAST(NULLIF(B12 , 0) AS FLOAT) AS C24
    B4 / CAST(NULLIF(B6 , 0) AS FLOAT)  AS C25
    B6 / CAST(NULLIF(B8,0) * NULLIF( B10,0) AS FLOAT) AS C26

    0.0 AS C27, 
    0.0 AS C28,
    0.0 AS C29,
    0.0 AS C30,
    0.0 AS C31,
    0.0 AS C32,
    0.0 AS C33,
    0.0 AS C34,
    0.0 AS C35,
    0.0 AS C36,
    0.0 AS C37,
    0.0 AS C38,
    0.0 AS C39,

    B13 AS C40
    B14 AS C41,
    B15 AS C42

  FROM (
         SELECT
           table_id,
           A1 - A2 + A3  AS B1,
           A1            AS B2,
           A4 - A5       AS B3,
           A4            AS B4,
           A6 - A7       AS B5,
           A6            AS B6,
           A8 - A9       AS B7,
           A8            AS B8,
           A10 - A11     AS B9,
           A10           AS B10,
           A12 - A13     AS B11,
           A12           AS B12,
           A14           AS B13,
           A15           AS B14,
           coalesce(coalesce(A16 * 100, 0) / NULLIF(A17, 0), 0) AS B15
         FROM my_table    
       ) v1;
```

I am running the above query as a background process using `psql` command
using below command

```
sudo -u postgres psql My_DB -X -a -f /tmp/test.sql > result.out 2>result.err &
```

Since my_table is a very huge table. But after sometime when I check result.err file. It has only one line saying

> ERROR:  integer out of range

For some sample ids in the WHere clause table gets generated without any issues but when i run it for entire table above error comes.

Can anyone explain why is this happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: cast every column where you have multiply ordivide opearation to bigint, eg `(A6 - A7)::bigint as B5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the `+` or `-` operations could cause this error, but the most likely cause is `A16 * 100`.

You can fix the problem by either avoiding operations that cause the overflow, or you could choose a data type like `numeric` or `bigint` that has a wider range of values.

Answer (score 1):

check the multiplications

```
NULLIF(B7, 0 )* NULLIF(B9,0)
```

and

```
NULLIF(B8,0) * NULLIF( B10,0)
```

try to replace the order of calculation, the first division, then multiplication

```
( B5 / NULLIF(B7, 0) ) * NULLIF(B9,0) AS B15
( B6 / NULLIF(B8, 0) ) * NULLIF(B10,0) AS C26
```